# Set Label in Python Node?

Tags: python, scripting, pynodes

So I am experimenting with python nodes. So far I am able to add a new node tree and my Nodes are doing things (adding and multiplying floats...well). One more cosmetic thing is that I don't get how to set a Label from this, I predefine values and a label:

```
    MyNodeCategory("OTHERNODES", "Predefined Nodes", items=[
    # the node item can have additional settings,
    # which are applied to new nodes
    # NB: settings values are stored as string expressions,
    # for this reason they should be converted to strings using repr()
    NodeItem("FloatInputNodeType",  label="Pi", settings={
        "wert": repr(math.pi),
        }),
```

But I have no idea how to get this into my added Nodes, the above is closely to the Custom_Nodes.py template which hints this should be possible, the settings/properties are copied ok. Then the code leaves my in the dark:

```
# Optional: custom label
# Explicit user label overrides this, but here we can define a label dynamically
def draw_label(self):
    return "I am a custom node"
```

which is not what I want :-) This of course sets the label to "I am a custom node" in the node itself but also not in the Label: field in the Node: sidebar.

Omitting the `def_label` uses the `bl_label`.

Comment: Why not just use the node.label that you can edit per each node instance in bpy.data? Are you looking to hardcode the label into the definition?

Comment: I have no idea how to get the info from the NodeItem() to the function draw_label...

Comment: By "label" what are referring to? Node has a "label"-property that is shown in the node editor property that is normally blank and can be edited by the user?

Comment: I define a label in MyNodeCategory() as in the source above. But this does NOT show up when the Node is created. There is a draw_label() function which can set the label by (i guess) self.node.label or such. But I have no idea where the label from MyNodeCategory() is gone in the way between...Does this makes sense?

Comment: Not in the slightest.